# Range intersection with bounding box?

Tags: algorithms

I have a lexicographical order on integer $n$-tuples, where $(x,y,\dots) > (a,b,\dots)$ if $x>a$ or if $x=a$ and $y>b$, and so on to the end of the tuple (I called it lexicographic because of its similarity to the natural order on strings of $n$ characters). In this order I have a range, defined inclusively by a pair of tuples.

I also have a rectangular box in $n$ dimensions defined by a pair of integer $n$-tuple corners. A tuple is in the box if every one of its elements is greater than the corresponding element in the first corner, and also less than the corresponding element in the second corner.

Given two tuples to serve as the ends of the range (under the lexicographic ordering), and another two tuples defining the corners of the box, I would like to determine if there is any overlap between the tuples in the range and the tuples in the box. What is the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can answer this in $O(n)$ time with a recursive algorithm, as follows.  It basically boils down to an ugly case analysis.

## Over the real numbers

Let me start by assuming you are working over the real numbers, to make it easier to present the ideas.

Suppose the range is $(r_1,r_2,\dots,r_n) \ldots (s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n)$ and the bounding box has corners $(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ and $(c_1,\dots,c_n)$ with $b_i \le c_i$ for all $i$.  There are four cases:

- If the intervals $[r_1,s_1]$ and $[b_1,c_1]$ don't overlap, then there is no overlap between your range and your bounding box.
- If $r_1=s_1$ or $r_1=c_1$, then check whether $b_1 \le r_1 \le c_1$ and then recurse on the $n-1$-dimensional problem obtained by forcing the first dimension to be $r_1$ (i.e., the range is $(r_2,\dots,r_n) \ldots (\infty,\dots,\infty)$ and the box has corners $(b_2,\dots,b_n)$ and $(c_2,\dots,c_n)$).
- If $r_1<s_1$ and $s_1=b_1$, then recurse on the $n-1$-dimensional problem obtained by forcing the first dimension to be $s_1$  (i.e., the range is $(-\infty,\dots,-\infty) \ldots (s_2,\dots,s_n)$ and the box has corners $(b_2,\dots,b_n)$ and $(c_2,\dots,c_n)$).
- Otherwise, the intervals $[r_1,s_1]$ and $[b_1,c_1]$ overlap at more than two points.  In this case, there is guaranteed to be an overlap between your range and your bounding box.  In particular, pick a value $x_1$ that is in the overlap and such that $r_1<x_1<s_1$; then $(x_1,b_2,\dots,b_n)$ is in the range and in the bounding box.

It is easy to see that this runs in $O(n)$ time, because the running time satisfies the recurrence $T(n) = T(n-1) + O(1)$.

## Over the integers

If you are dealing with integers, then it suffices to add the following cases just before the "Otherwise":

- If $s_1=r_1+1$, recurse twice: recurse on the range $(r_1,r_n,\dots,r_n)\ldots (r_1,\infty,\dots,\infty)$ and recurse again on the range $(s,-\infty,\dots,-\infty) \ldots (s_1,s_2,\dots,s_n)$ (leaving the bounding box alone).  If either of them finds a point of overlap, then you have found an overlap between your range and your bounding box.  (*)
- If $c_1=b_1+1$, then there is a point of overlap.  (If $r_1<b_1<c_1\le s_1$, use $(b_1,\dots,b_n)$); if $r_1 \le b_1<c_1 < s_1$, use $(c_1,\dots,c_n)$); those are the only two possibilities.)

The running time with this modification remains $O(n)$.  It takes a little more work to see why, though.  Naively, we obtain the recurrence $T(n)=2 T(n-1) + O(1)$, due to need to recurse twice in the case marked (*); and this recurrence satisfies $T(n)=O(2^n)$, which is very bad.  Fortunately, this is an overly loose upper bound.  Note that when $(r_1,\dots,r_n) = (-\infty,\dots,-\infty)$ or $(s_1,\dots,s_n)=(\infty,\dots,\infty)$, then we never invoke the case (*) in any subsequent recursion.  So, when running on one of those inputs, the running time is $O(n)$.  Moreover, the case (*) recurses on inputs of this form.  Thus, we will never invoke case (*) more than once in the entire recursion tree.  Thus, the entire recursion tree can involve at most $2n$ recursive calls.  Thus, the total running time remains $O(n)$.

This algorithm looks a pretty messy, with at least 6 different cases.  Perhaps there is a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was dealing with integer tuples. I have edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: @DisplayName, have you thought about how to handle those cases and whether you can apply similar ideas to them?  I'd be interested to hear your analysis of them.  I haven't given them any thought yet.

Comment: @DisplayName, see updated answer for an analysis of those cases.  I hope I haven't made any mistakes, but if you implement this, I encourage you to test it extensively, and check my reasoning.  Maybe someone else will find a cleaner algorithm that doesn't require such a messy case analysis.

Comment: I independently worked out the case where the side lengths of the box were either 1 or infinite, and my result looked similar to yours. Its implementation is also a tangled system of cases. Perhaps that's just the nature of the problem.